# Given a polygon in latitude and longitude and a set of points, determine which points lie inside

Tags: geometry, geospatial

Given a set of latlon points that make up a polygon, and a set of latlon points, how can I determine which points lie inside. The polygon may be up to 100km across and the error could be a few hundred meters (i.e. points inside or outside can fail or be included incorrectly at the edges). The polygons and points won't be near the poles. Can I treat the latlon points as 2d, or do I need to convert them to a projection of some kind? Circles are easy but I wonder if the error will be too great for a 100km wide polygon?

I plan to do this in C++ but the language doesn't matter.

Comment: Stack Overflow -- where other people get credit for answering your homework for you.

Comment: Simplest accurate implementation would be to convert the vertices and the point in question from spherical coords (lon,lat,altitude) to to cartesian (x,y,z) relative to the center of the planet.  Then for each face consisting of 2 vertices and the origin (center of the planet), calculate the signed minimum distance from the point to that plane.  If all of these distances are positive (or negative, depending on which direction your normal is) then the point is in the polygon (assuming a convex polygon is used)

Comment: Last time I did homework dinosaurs ruled the earth.

Comment: I can do a point in poly, I was wondering about the likely error if I only consider the x,y in a cartesian system.

Comment: [This answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/2964/21312) might be helpful.

Comment: If your max polygon width is only 100KM and you're tolerant of some errors, then a point-in-poly method like ray casting should work fine for lat-lng coordinates.   See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809572/latitude-longitude-as-coordinates-adequate-for-point-in-polygon-algorithm

Comment: Thank you both, very interesting references. However I can't accept them since it's just a comment. Of course SO doesn't like references as answers though in this case they are quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the (javascript) code from Openlayers to do it

```
/**
 * Method: containsPoint
 * Test if a point is inside a polygon.  Points on a polygon edge are
 *     considered inside.
 *
 * Parameters:
 * point - {<OpenLayers.Geometry.Point>}
 *
 * Returns:
 * {Boolean | Number} The point is inside the polygon.  Returns 1 if the
 *     point is on an edge.  Returns boolean otherwise.
 */
containsPoint: function(point) {
    var numRings = this.components.length;
    var contained = false;
    if(numRings > 0) {
        // check exterior ring - 1 means on edge, boolean otherwise
        contained = this.components[0].containsPoint(point);
        if(contained !== 1) {
            if(contained && numRings > 1) {
                // check interior rings
                var hole;
                for(var i=1; i<numRings; ++i) {
                    hole = this.components[i].containsPoint(point);
                    if(hole) {
                        if(hole === 1) {
                            // on edge
                            contained = 1;
                        } else {
                            // in hole
                            contained = false;
                        }                            
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return contained;
}
```

Complete file can be found at [Openlayers at Github](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Geometry/Polygon.js)
To get the idea behind `this.components` have a look at [Collection.js](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Geometry/Collection.js)

**update:**

In OpenLayers a polygon is a collection of linear rings. the `containsPoint` functon of this can be found at [LinearRing.js](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Geometry/LinearRing.js)

Comment: So each component is what?  a polygon?  a triangle?  This seems like it just uses `component.containsPoint` multiple times to calculate it for a complex object made up of multiple polygons.  The implementation of `containsPoint` is what the OP really needs.

Comment: LinearRing uses 2D cartesian coordinates, thus this code works for determining if a point on a map is inside a polygon on a map.  OP's question wasn't particularly clear but treating lon/lat as x/y is essentially an equirectangular projection, so that could work for that.  But a straight line on an equirectangular projection is usually a curved line on a sphere

Comment: So using a 2d cartesian coordinate is a reasonable approach? How would you go about determining the error assuming it's flat at a scale of 100km?

Answer (score 1):

You can view actual demo [here](http://www.codeace.in/download/gmap/gm3.php)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>How to Check If Point Exist in a Polygon - Google Maps API v3</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.the-di-lab.com/polygon/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var boundaryPolygon;
        function initialize() {

            var mapProp = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(26.038586842564317, 75.06787185438634),
                zoom: 6,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapProp);

            google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Contains = function (point) {
                // ray casting alogrithm http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ray-casting_algorithm
                var crossings = 0,
            path = this.getPath();

                // for each edge
                for (var i = 0; i < path.getLength() ; i++) {
                    var a = path.getAt(i),
                j = i + 1;
                    if (j >= path.getLength()) {
                        j = 0;
                    }
                    var b = path.getAt(j);
                    if (rayCrossesSegment(point, a, b)) {
                        crossings++;
                    }
                }

                // odd number of crossings?
                return (crossings % 2 == 1);

                function rayCrossesSegment(point, a, b) {
                var px = point.lng(),
                py = point.lat(),
                ax = a.lng(),
                ay = a.lat(),
                bx = b.lng(),
                by = b.lat();
                    if (ay > by) {
                        ax = b.lng();
                        ay = b.lat();
                        bx = a.lng();
                        by = a.lat();
                    }
                    if (py == ay || py == by) py += 0.00000001;
                    if ((py > by || py < ay) || (px > Math.max(ax, bx))) return false;
                    if (px < Math.min(ax, bx)) return true;

                    var red = (ax != bx) ? ((by - ay) / (bx - ax)) : Infinity;
                    var blue = (ax != px) ? ((py - ay) / (px - ax)) : Infinity;
                    return (blue >= red);
                }
            };


            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {

                if (boundaryPolygon != null && boundaryPolygon.Contains(event.latLng)) {
                    alert("in")
                    document.getElementById("spnMsg").innerText = "This location is " + event.latLng + " inside the polygon.";
                } else {
                    alert("out")
                    document.getElementById("spnMsg").innerText = "This location is " + event.latLng + " outside the polygon.";
                }

            });
        }


        function drawPolygon() {

            initialize();
            var boundary = '77.702866 28.987153, 77.699776 28.978594 ,77.735996 28.974164 ,77.719946 28.99346 ,77.713423 28.994361 ,77.711706 28.990382 ';
            var boundarydata = new Array();

            var latlongs = boundary.split(",");

            for (var i = 0; i < latlongs.length; i++) {
                latlong = latlongs[i].trim().split(" ");
                boundarydata[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(latlong[1], latlong[0]);
            }

            boundaryPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                path: boundarydata,
                strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: 'Red',
                fillOpacity: 0.4

            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(boundaryPolygon, 'click', function (event) {
                document.getElementById("spnMsg").innerText = '';
                if (boundaryPolygon.Contains(event.latLng)) {
                    document.getElementById("spnMsg").innerText = "This location is " + event.latLng + " inside the polygon.";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("spnMsg").innerText = "This location is " + event.latLng + " outside the polygon.";
                }

            });
            map.setZoom(14);
            map.setCenter(boundarydata[0]);
            boundaryPolygon.setMap(map);

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize();drawPolygon();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <h3>Check If Point Exist in a Polygon</h3>
        <h3>click on the polygon and out side the polygon for testing</h3>
        <span id="spnMsg" style="font-family: Arial; text-align: center; font-size: 14px; color: red;">this is message</span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="map-canvas" style="width: auto; height: 500px;">
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

you can view more demos may be use full to you here
http://codeace.in/download/gmap/

you can download all the demo
by click on the file

"googlemap.zip" given in the index

Comment: the link is broken